# There are total $2^4=16$ possible output combinations (truth functions) for $2$ binary input variables.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> Let $p$ and $q$ be two propositions. Each of these statements can take two values - true ( $T$ ) and false ( $F$ ). So there are 4 pairs of input values: $T T, T F, F T$, and $F F $.
>
> Suppose that a new proposition $r$ is composed of $p$ and $q$. The truth values of the proposition $r$ can take different values ( $T$ or $F$ ) for each pair of input values.

[image: Here is an image of the topic.]

Can somebody please explain to me the sentence below, using truth table maybe.

> There are total $2^{4}=16$ possible output combinations  (truth functions) for 2 binary input variables. Each of these combinations is represented by a certain logical operator.

Comment: You have $A$ different inputs, and you must assign one of $B$ output values to each, so $B^A$ total possible output combinations. In your case $A=4, B=2$.

Comment: sorry am new and English is not my first language.

Comment: @ adityarawat I have edited the question to make it sound better, hope @jjagmath will agree. Now to understand what exactly is confusing you. Did you find dxiv's comment above useful at all?

Comment: @adityarawat I retracted my votes since @ StrikingBishop fixed your question. I understand, English is not your first language, but isn't there an equivalent to the word "please" in your language? Also, no matter the language, using UPPERCASE is considered the typing analog to screaming, so you should avoid that.

Comment: thanks guys now i have understood the statement ,so it has 4 inputs from p and q propositions (each binary) . so r have total combination for each input as 2*2*2*2. (there can be 2 condition true or false.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preceding text and diagram are very misleading, not to mention confusing.

> There are total $2^4=16$ possible output combinations (truth functions) for 2 binary input variables.

This sentence, in isolation, is more clear. A "binary input" variable, is one requiring two inputs. "binary" seems to be an unfortunate choice of words, since it usually refers to the binary number system.

We take 4 propositions, say $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, each can be true or false. We determine $p$ from a logical gate on $A$ and $B$; then determine $q$ from a logical gate on $C$ and $D$. Finally we apply a logical gate on $p$ and $q$, obtaining $r$. When looking at $r$ from $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, then there are $2^4$ possibilities.